# React Native Typescript, pass variable to another screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I cant seem to figure how to pass variable with typescript in react native, I have tried the params but its saying undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.props.value').

below are the codes.

```
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/core';
const navigation = useNavigation();

.......

<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('NewsDetails', {value: 'hi', })}>
                  <Block row flex={0} align="center">
                    <Text
                      p
                      color={colors.link}
                      semibold
                      size={sizes.linkSize}
                      marginRight={sizes.s}>
                      Read Article
                    </Text>
                    <Image source={assets.arrow} color={colors.link} />
                  </Block>
                </TouchableOpacity>
```

then to display it in screen be this is what I had done but its not working

```
<Text p marginBottom={sizes.s}>
               {navigation.props.value}
</Text>
```

Comment: I think it should be `route.params.value`.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Answer (score 4):

React navigation pass variables as *params*, not *props*. You can pass it using hooks, but then you will need to use the useRoute hook to get the route in the next screen, then get it as route.params.value

```
const nextScreen = () => {
  const route = useRoute()

  return <Text>route.params.value</Text>
}
```

Please notice that you can pass the navigation and route props from the navigator stack, and then you shouldn't need to use hooks:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-route

Comment: Hi it says Can't find variable: useRoute

Comment: Never mind , found it, it now works....thank you

Comment: If it was correct can you please mark it as correct answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since `NewsDetails` is a screen where you can navigate to, it is handled by a navigator, thus the `route` and the `navigation` props are passed to this screen by the navigator. You can access this in your `NewsDetails` component from the screen props directly as follows.

```js
const NewsDetails = ({route}) => {

   const value = route.params.value

   return (...)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the other answers didn't work in TypeScript because there was no `value` in `route.params.value`. However the solution that worked for me to get the data was to call the `valueOf` method like this:

```
const route = useRoute();
if(route.params != undefined){
    const data = route.params.valueOf() as DataType; // insert fitting datatype for the object you give the navigate method
    return (...);
}
else {
    ...
}
```